# Redirect to current page after login/logout in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication, multisite

I have some websites in wordpress (using the multisite function). All of them are in one domain. E.g.: www.mymainsite.com (the others are: www.mymainsite.com/mysite2, www.mymainsite.com/mysite3 etc).
Also I have some pages that the user have to login to access the content. All working very well, so far... except for the login. When a user sign in wordpress successfully it redirects to dashboard and when sign out it redirects to the login page.

Now, my question...
What can I do for, in this case, when users sign in/sign out the wordpress redirect to the current page. Something like:

E.g.: You go to a page and have a message "content avaiable only for users logged in. Click *here* to login." When you click and make a successful login, the content of this page will be shown to you.

P.S.: If I didn't made myself clear enough, please let me know.

Comment: <?php wp_loginout($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>

Comment: @hemnathmouli I have to put this in every single page that needs this function? Or can I put in one file that works for all my sites?

Comment: Simply add this code to your parent or child themes functions.php
Refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout